# Defining object part in callbyname function with variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing a problem when I want to rewrite part of my program. This part is put in module1 and look like as follows:

```
Public Function InputCorr(Target As MSForms.Control) As Boolean

    If FrmAddRecord1Shown Then
        Target.Value = CallByName(frmAddRecord1, Target.Name & "_Min", VbMethod)
    ElseIf FrmAddRecord2Shown Then
        Target.Value = CallByName(frmAddRecord2, Target.Name & "_Min", VbMethod)
    End If

End Function
```

And I am going to rewrite like this:

```
Public Function InputCorr(Target As MSForms.Control) As Boolean

    Dim UF As UserForm

    If FrmAddRecord1Shown Then
        set UF = frmAddRecord1
    ElseIf FrmAddRecord2Shown Then
        set UF = frmAddRecord2
    EndIf 

    Target.Value = CallByName(UF, Target.Name & "_Min", VbMethod)

End Function
```

FrmAddRecord1Shown and FrmAddRecord2Shown are boolean, indicating which userform (frmAddRecord1 or frmAddRecord2)is active.

However, "run-time error"438": Object doesn't spport this property or method" occurs. I believe I was stuck at the "UF" defining part. Is it possible for me to define the "object" part of "callbyname" function with variable? Please advice. Thank you very much for all yours sincere help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CallByName(object, procname, calltype, [args()])` (Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/callbyname-function) performs an action on the `object` during run-time (late binding). Before using `CallByName` , your should make sure that the equivalent early binding operation works.

Depending on the `calltype` you use in `CallByName`, the `procname` corresponds to different members of the `object`: (The following cases are expressed in the form of "late-binding corresponds to early-binding")

(1) `CallByName(object, procname, calltype:=vbGet)` corresponds to `object.[Property]`

(2) `CallByName(object, procname, calltype:=vbLet)` corresponds to `object.[Property, which is a value]`

(3) `CallByName(object, procname, calltype:=vbMethod)` corresponds to `object.[Method]`

(4) `CallByName(object, procname, calltype:=vbSet)` corresponds to `object.[Property, which is an object]`

Now, in your function, you are performing on the `UF` object (an `UserForm` object) with `CallByName(UF, procname, VbMethod)`, which corresponds to Case (3) mentioned above. Therefore, your `procname` should be a Method of the `UserForm` object. You can check the Methods of the `UserForm` object in the Object Browser (press F2 in the VBA editor, and find UserForm under the MSForms Libary). The Methods are listed in the following code: (DO NOT run the code, the codes do not do anything.)

```
Private Sub UserFormMethods()
    Dim ufForm As UserForm

    Set ufForm = frmAddRecord1

    With ufForm
        .Copy
        .Cut
        .Paste
        .RedoAction
        .Repaint
        .Scroll
        .SetDefaultTabOrder
        .UndoAction
    End With
End Sub
```

However, in your `CallByName` function, your `procname` argument is `Target.Name`. `Target` in your definition is an `MSForms.Control` object, which is an object PROPERTY, not a METHOD, of the `UserForm` object. Therefore it triggers the "run-time error"438": Object doesn't spport this property or method" error.

I think what you are trying to do is actually using `CallByName` on the `Target` object (an `MSForms.Control` object). I would suggest changing your function to:

```
Public Function InputCorr(Target As MSForms.Control) As Boolean
    Dim UF As UserForm
    Dim ctlTarget As MSForms.Control

    If FrmAddRecord1Shown Then
        Set UF = frmAddRecord1
    ElseIf FrmAddRecord2Shown Then
        Set UF = frmAddRecord2
    End If

    Set ctlTarget = CallByName(UF, Target.Name, VbGet)
    Call CallByName(ctlTarget, "_Min", VbMethod)
End Function
```

I was not able to find the `MSForms.Control._Min` method in the object browser. Maybe it is a hidden method but you must make sure this method exists.

Also, you did not specify what your function's return value is. It should have a final line like: `InputCorr = ...`

Comment: Thank you very much for you detailed description of my problem step by step. But I am so stupid and too green in vba, I can't fully understand. As my function work fine before replacing the "frmAddRecord1" and "frmAddRecord2" with variables, I believe there are problems with my declaration.

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of your function?

Comment: I found out the reason, as frmAddarecord2 is class, not userform, thefunction works smooth now with the correct type.